# My published pod don't appear in CocoaPods search engine

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I recently published a pod called StickyButton which doesn't appear in CocoaPods main search. I use pod v1.8.4. Here my pod's link http://cocoapods.org/pods/StickyButton and the last time I updated it was 9 days ago.

I have seen few posts about the problem but no solution.

Thank you,

Comment: it appears in the main search

Comment: Are you sure you're not mistaking with "SpicyButton" ? https://imgur.com/J4UeOuO

Comment: You need to add your git url after the pod. For example, you need to pod 'StickyButton', :git => 'https://github.com/path-to-your-StickyButton-repo'

Answer (score 0):

Just small action needed after publishing your podspec before updating, your repository always not found

**pod update StickyButton**

Comment: sorry I don't understand, **pod update StickyButton** is for a project which uses the pod and I'm talking about my pod in the main search of cocoapods.org. Please have a look to this screenshot https://imgur.com/J4UeOuO